# how to use ggsurvfit to add at risk table inside of KM plot and color code groups?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, ggsurvfit

I could not find syntax to add at risk table inside of KM plot and color code groups like SAS do. I know the package was published recently, so I'm not sure if there is any syntax for that.

I followed the guidance [https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/ggsurvfit/reference/add_risktable.html] to use ggsurvfit to generate KM plot.

Answer (score 1):

The examples are fairly clear on the help pages. Here's an example of a color-coded KM with a risk table, using the `df_lung` data frame that comes with the ggsurvfit package:

```r
library(ggsurvfit)

survfit2(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = df_lung) %>%
  ggsurvfit() +
  scale_ggsurvfit(x_scales = list(breaks = seq(0, 30, by = 6))) +
  add_risktable()
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

If you are looking for something more bespoke, with the risk table as part of the main panel, you can place the text directly in it, but it requires some precalculation:

```r
library(ggsurvfit)
library(tidyverse)

survdat <- ggsurvfit(survfit2(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = df_lung))$data

risk_table <- survdat %>% 
  group_by(strata) %>% 
  filter(c(TRUE, diff(n.risk) != 0)) %>%
  mutate(timecut = cut(time, breaks = c(-Inf, 0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30), 
                       include.lowest = FALSE)) %>%
  group_by(strata, timecut) %>%
  slice_max(time, n = 1) %>%
  filter(time < 30) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(time = seq(0, 30, 6), .by = 'strata')
```

The plot is now:

```r
ggplot(survdat, aes(time, estimate, color = strata)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0:4 * 0.25, color = 'gray', linewidth = 0.25) +
  geom_segment(inherit.aes = FALSE, data = data.frame(x = seq(0, 30, 6)),
               color = 'gray', linewidth = 0.25,
               aes(x = x, xend = x, y = 0, yend = Inf)) +
  geom_step() +
  geom_text(aes(y = as.numeric(strata)*-0.1, label = n.risk),
            show.legend = FALSE, data = risk_table) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  scale_y_continuous('Survival Probability',
                     breaks = c(-0.1, -0.2, 0:4 * 0.25), 
                     labels = ~ c(paste('n at risk', 
                                  levels(survdat$strata)[.x[.x < 0] * -10]),
                                  scales::percent(.x[.x >= 0]))) +
  scale_x_continuous('Time (months)', breaks = seq(0, 30, 6)) +
  scale_color_manual(NULL, values = c('blue3', 'red4')) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom',
        panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I can get the same plot as you did. I would like to have the at risk table inside of the plot not outside. also, the numbers in the table can be color coded as the line in the plot. for example, numbers for male are red. Those are what I want to have for the KM plot.

Comment: @user23097547 your question was a bit vague on the exact details. Could you provide a reproducible example? I'm sure I can provide code that does what you ask, but it is dependent on your data and the shape of your KM curve. Perhaps include some data in `dput` format, and include a sample image of what you would like to see. There is no default option to do this in ggsurvfit, so it would have to be a bespoke solution for your data.

Comment: Also, any SAS examples I have seen show the risk table _below_ the plot

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. i don't know how to paste an SAS KM plot image in this comment box, but I can provide the link [https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/stat/141/kaplan.pdf]. On page 12, the plot is what i would like to have using ggsurvfit or R.  I don't know how to include a reproducible code in this comment, but would you please just use df_lung data? Then I would be able to mimic your code.

Comment: @user23097547 I think this looks very similar to the plot I have added?

Comment: wow, it's very impressive. Yes, it's the plot. Thank you very much.